# мне надо чтобы таймер threading остановил цикл в python

Tags: python

В общем есть цикл, в нем каждый раз запрашивается ввод и если время выходит цикл должен остановиться. Погуглил там был только пример с остановкой кода, можно ли остановить именно цикл?

Comment: таймер для ввода в каждой итерации? или в общем таймер который остановит цикл как только пройдет время и неважно сколько вводов было принято?

Comment: @zolars лучше первый вариант, но будет неплохо хоть что-то

Answer (score 0):

Единственный адекватный вариант, это использование модуля `multiprocessing` и задача в нем, при объявлении, параметра `timeout`

[Пример](https://gist.github.com/tappoz/cb88f7a9d9ba27cfee1e2f03537fac16)